# Restrict file access in php.ini

Tags: php, file-access

What is the difference between `include_path` and `open_basedir` in PHP? My `php.ini` looks like this:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www"
```

If, for example, I try using `include('../../etc/passwd');` the file is included. On the other hand, when I'm modifying my `php.ini` like this the output is empty:

```
open_basedir = /var/www
```

Why is this? I thought that using `include_path` will restrict the file access to the directories listed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) directive is a list of directories to look for included files first, similar to bash's $PATH environmental variable.

So an absolute file name/path like this:

```
include_once('/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/includes/header.php');
include_once('/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/includes/footer.php');
```

Can be replaced with a relative filename like this:

```
include_path('/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/includes:.');
include_once('header.php');
include_once('footer.php');
```

This is at least how I understand it. It has nothing to do with security and restricting directories, it is to create a custom search path for common includes.

[open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is what you are looking for, it limits the reading of files to the directories specified. Based on your question, it looks as though it is operating as designed.